# angular 4 custom form validator

Tags: spring-rest, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

We have a requirement to change attributes of form fields like "required", "hidden", "maxLength" based on selection of one or more fields on the form.

For eg: Based on country selected from a dropdown, the city,state,address1, address2, address3 attributes should change. State may be mandatory for US but not India.

Currently we are using a server side technology JSF2 to implement the view. Spring REST is used as backend. All these country based rules are currently stored in a database table. On application start up these are loaded in memory and derived based on country selection in the view.

In case we need to switch the view to angular 4, please advice if we can reuse this existing rules configuration table to dynamically update the attributes of form fields based on country selection?

Based on checking, angular 4 reactive forms seems to what we can use. It has FormValidators but not sure if these can be dynamically derived/changed based on country based rules derived from backend REST service (in JSON) when country is changed.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated

Thanks and Regards,
Jacob